# Can't upload arduino code on the board due to some programmer issues

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

As I connected my arduino-uno board and made sure of the "Board" selected, and the "Port" selected as well. There is a problem while uploading, I tried updating the arduino IDE, reinstalling all the arduino drivers, I tried to borrow a new arduino board from a friend and I am 100% sure it is working.

The message I get from the IDE:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM5
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1d

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all thank you for replying,
I double checked the chip and it is atmega328 and I am selecting the board.
But I want to try to change the baud rate to 9600 (Overriding Baud Rate) but I do not know how, do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while uploading.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

To solve that I changed my port to another USB port and I selected the particular port, Its uploaded successfully. But it's in MacBook not in Windows.

Try this once, by changing the port.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing baud rate to 9600.

Another thing to check is the chip your Uno has. My Uno has the atmega328. Make sure you select that board.

Comment: **All** Unos will have the Atmega328P.

Comment: The ide does not allow you to upload sketches? If it does not allow you to upload to your oard or your friends board i would assume the issue is witb the software. Maybe try reinstalling the ide. I had the same error problem with a avrdude and the buad rate was wrong. That might not be the case with yours.